# Office 365 API limitation to Subscription Plan? And prerequisites?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

2 questions:

1. Does Graph API apply to all O365 subscription plan without difference? (Business/Business Essential/E1/E2/E5/Education/etc.)
2. What's the prerequisites for O365 user to use an Application using O365 APIS? (For example, a O365 Trial version user, or a user only activate O365 but didn't create Azure AD, will it pass authentication process?)

Thanks,
Raymond,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Graph API is a standard endpoint regardless your subscription plan you are in. It is your integration point to build app and it exposes all o365 functionality.

2) You need to register any office 365 app into Azure AD (AAD) regardless if a user is trial or not you should implement your licensing model for this.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you Mostafa! So do we have APIs to determine if the user is in trial or specific subscription plan?

Comment: Glai helped. There is a API for Subscribed SKU which gives you a count for all SKUs and associated license. Check this out: https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/subscribedsku